# Idomatic way to do 'require if not null' in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, validation, parameters

I have a function in kotlin where I want to use 'require' to validate an input parameter. The catch is, NULL is a valid input so I only want to do the require check if the value is not null. I know I can simply use an if statement like:

```
fun getEmergencyAddresses(dp: MyDependencyProvider, siteId: String, level:Int?=null){

    if(level != null) {
        require(level in 0..2)
        {
            "level must be 0, 1, or 2"
        }
    }
}
```

but I feel like that is a very 'java' way of doing things for lack of a better term. Is there a more idomatic 'kotlin' way of writing this code?

Comment: So just `require(level == null || level in 0..2)`?

Comment: I would absolutely consider the idiomatic Kotlin way to be the code you already wrote without changes.

Answer (score 4):

You have some alternatives:

**1. As Sweeper's comment suggests:**

```
require(level == null || level in 0..2)
```

This is very efficient as it compiles into code similar to `if (level == null || level >= 0 && level <= 2)`.

**2. If you prefer to use the name "level" just once:**

```
require(level in (0..2) + null)
```

This is not very efficient as it builds an `ArrayList<Int?>` behind the scenes and then iterates through the list to check if it contains `level`.

**3. Use an enum:**

```
enum class Level { LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH }

fun getEmergencyAddresses(
    dp: MyDependencyProvider,
    siteId: String,
    level: Level? = null
)
```

Now, you don't have to do any validation checks at all! The validation is done at design time, as you can only pass valid parameters. If it compiles, it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
level?.let { require(level in 0..2) }
```

Comment: That’s not idiomatic if `level` is a local variable, and if it’s not a local variable, it can’t be smart-casted so it won’t compile.

Comment: `level` is a local variable in the question, and I answered this question, not another one. As for what is idiomatic, that is not so easy for one person to decide.

Comment: True, what’s idiomatic is sometimes more debatable.